# When I tried to apply BABE in solo chain, I got LightSyncStateExtensionNotFound error

Tags: babe

When I tried to apply BABE in solo chain, I got this error

```
2023-12-27 07:30:39  Operating system: macos    
2023-12-27 07:30:39  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2023-12-27 07:30:39  Highest known block at #0    
2023-12-27 07:30:39 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
Error: Service(Application(LightSyncStateExtensionNotFound))
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

miss the extension

```
#[derive(Default, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, ChainSpecExtension)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Extensions {
    /// Block numbers with known hashes.
    pub fork_blocks: sc_client_api::ForkBlocks<Block>,
    /// Known bad block hashes.
    pub bad_blocks: sc_client_api::BadBlocks<Block>,
    /// The light sync state extension used by the sync-state rpc.
    pub light_sync_state: sc_sync_state_rpc::LightSyncStateExtension,
}

pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<RuntimeGenesisConfig, Extensions>;
```

in chain_spec.rs